# MIT AppInventor list Error : Attempt to get item number 0, of the list [5]

Tags: list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, foreach, app-inventor

" Select list item: Attempt to get item number 0, of the list [5]. The minimum valid item number is 1.
Note: You will not see another error reported for 5 seconds. "

Hey Guys,
The message on top appear when the app open the app not crashing but I need to click somewhere on screen few times till it disappear..

The idea is to search a value of var 'UID' in firebase.database and when it found it I need to get the value of is brother key..

I want you please to help me to clear this message I tried a few ways to get the result but nothing yet..

Thanks a lot for helpers :)

[When Screen Open.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKkOX.png)

[This is how I tried to get the uid && employeeKey.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVRTX.png)

[for your help me I set var 'UID' = to uid value of employee number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4L4M.png)

'UID' get the value from firebase.auth form on screen 1..

Answer (score 0):

The **index in list** block returns 0, if the "thing" has not been found in the list and in this case you are trying to get the value from the 0th item from the empKey list, which does not make sense.

[image]

Therefore you will have to add an if statement... if the returned index is 0, then do not search for the empKey.

Btw. the better place to ask questions like this would be the [MIT App Inventor](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/) community...